# Why is my subfolder not being ignored in my .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

**Description**

I am trying to ignore a subfolder in my project, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have a .gitignore at the root level of my project. Also at the root there is an api folder that contains a firebase folder. This is the folder I am trying to ignore. The structure is:

```
api/firebase/test.js
```

**Attempts at solution**

I have tried putting the following in my .gitignore at the root level:

```
firebase/
api/firebase/
**/api/firebase
**/firebase
```

And none of it works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Git doesn't commit (or ignore) directories. Have you added/committed files inside that folder before ignoring?

Comment: Inside the api folder yes, but not in the firebase folder.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Git doesn't commit directories, but it does (sort of!) *ignore* them. In particular, when doing a working-tree scan for untracked files, if Git comes across a directory and that directory is listed in `.gitignore`, that enables Git to not scan the inside of that directory. As you note, this gets iffy at best if there are files in the directory that are already tracked: those files definitely need to be scanned.

Comment: To the OP: show the output from `git rev-parse --show-cdup` if it's not empty, and the output from `git status` or `git status --short`. Also, make sure the `.gitignore` file contents are in UTF-8 (especially if you are on Windows) - UTF-16 / UCS-2 doesn't work.

Comment: @torek good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
api/firebase/*.js
```

?

If you have already added the folder previously (as in committed it), you might need to run one of these as well:

```
git rm --cached <file>
git rm --cached api/firebase/*.js
git rm --cached api/firebase/test.js
```

to remove it from git's memory, else just adding the file to gitignore won't work